# Get all objects from Parse.com C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I am using the Parse.com service to store names, Facebook IDs, scores and e-mail for my game.

So far, I can get one specific object (by specifying the unique objectID generated by Parse), but how can I get the first 10 objects sorted by the score value?

This is the code I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Parse;

public class GetFromParse : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void getParseResults()
    {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("IdealStunts");
        query.GetAsync("xWMyZ4YEGZ").ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            ParseObject gameScore = t.Result;
            float time = gameScore.Get<int>("time");
            string playerName = gameScore.Get<string>("name");
            string fbid = gameScore.Get<string>("fbid");
            string email = gameScore.Get<string>("email");
        });
    }
}
```

This only gets me the values for that specific objectID (*xWMyZ4YEGZ*), but not being a programmer, I have absolutely NO clue on how to get the rest and store them for usage.

I know that for sorting and getting the first 10 results I can use

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("GameScore")
    .OrderBy("score")
    .Limit(10);
```

But I don't know where to go from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turns out is in changing the generic type to float or int instead of ParseObject:

```
var score = obj.Get<float>("score");
        Debug.Log("Score: " + score);
```

[Parse.com - How can I get all objects from a class in C#/Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302589/parse-com-how-can-i-get-all-objects-from-a-class-in-c-unity/23170857#23170857)

Comment: If i have DateTime field 'ExpiredOn', will this work ?
var expiry = obj.Get<DateTime>("ExpiredOn");

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass the object ID in the query.

Assuming you saved a score like this:

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore["score"] = 1337;
Task saveTask = gameScore.SaveAsync();
```

then you'll have to do something like this to retrieve some scores:

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("GameScore").OrderBy("score").Limit(10);
query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;
    foreach (var obj in results)
    {
        var score = obj.Get<ParseObject>("score");
        Debug.Log("Score: " + score);
    }
});
```

You might want to try Kii Cloud instead which is easier (see section "Retrieve Game Data"):

http://docs.kii.com/en/samples/Gamecloud-Unity/

Comment: Kii is really nice and easy, but what's really putting me off is that the players have to register/login.

Comment: Unfortunately, the loop doesn't start.

Comment: Double check that you're using the correct object name (eg. "GameScore") and the correct field (eg. "score") both when saving the object and in the query. The loop not executing means there are no objects matching the query.

Comment: I have checked and rechecked, and I'm not getting anything, not even errors.

Comment: Do you see the objects using the web interface?

Comment: Yes, they are all there.

Comment: Nothing inside the callback gets executed? Try to debug if IEnumerable<ParseObject> results is empty or not

Comment: IEnumerable<ParseObject> returns

System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[Parse.ParseObject]

Comment: Seems you get a collection from the query. Now try to debug what's the number of elements inside that collection and see if that what you should expect. If element count seems correct then there's a problem with retrieving the data inside the foreach

Comment: What is the max limit of objects per query for KiiCloud? anyone know. Parse is 1000

Comment: That's not part of the Kii API spec or contract. It depends on several conditions. Please take a look at the section "Pagination" here http://docs.kii.com/en/guides/rest/managing-data/object-storages/querying/ (and take a look at the bestEffortLimit parameter). bestEffortLimit is set to 200 by default and then you can paginate the results. My advice is you play with bestEffortLimit values and retrieving data similar to what you're going to use in order to see how it works out for you.

Comment: what about datetime ?