# Parse.com - How can I get all objects from a class in C#/Unity?

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I need to get all objects in a class from Parse.com, but my code does not seem to be working.

So far, I have this:

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("GameScore").OrderBy("score").Limit(10);
query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;
    foreach (var obj in results)
    {
        var score = obj.Get<ParseObject>("score");
        Debug.Log("Score: " + score);
    }
});
```

However, this does not return anything. I believe it doesn't even enter the loop.

EDIT: The class does exist, the keys are all there.

Comment: Anything related to Unity3D?

Comment: I'm assigning the first 10 items to different gameobjects (texture, and two texts), but I don't think it has any relevance in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

```
var score = obj.Get<ParseObject>("score");
```

should be

```
var score = obj.Get<float>("score");
```

Comment: If i have DateTime field 'ExpiredOn', will this work ? var expiry = obj.Get<DateTime>("ExpiredOn");